# Android string.xml and style.xml parsing error

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

```
 <style name="ButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
  </style>
```

I am getting this weird error saying 'Originally posted here' on line

`<item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>` 
in my xml file. I am using android 2.3.

I am also getting error in style.xml

```
 <style name="ButtonText" parent="BaseTopBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
 </style>
```

The error is 'Resource entry ButtonText already has bag item android:textSize'

Can someone help please.

Comment: Please post text, not images, or at least provide a textual description as well as an image.

Comment: @user958263 Are you setting textsize property two time, may be this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like everything is right in your string.xml file
You just need to clean and build your project.

if it doesn't work delete the bin/ and gen/ directory from your project than clean build your project.

and the error will not be shown anymore.hope it will help.

Comment: make sure there is no file like filename.out.xml anywhere in your project.

Comment: there isnt. This is so annoying its not generating R.java file due to errors mentioned above.

Comment: please try restarting eclipse.i know that may not b the error but just try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22623/discussion-between-user958263-and-neurenor)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but when using multiple array lists in my strings.xml.

[image]

It turned out that I had duplicate names for the arrays where I'd copied and pasted values.

Check that the style name **ButtonText** isn't duplicated somewhere else. You should have a corresponding error like the image below:

[image]